# how do i write and read a three dimensional dynamic char array to a file?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fwrite, dynamic-arrays

i have this array

```
char ***three_dim=0;
```

**three_dim** is allocated and populated with data.
After this I have to write its content to a file and read back.
I have tried the following to write it but it fails.

```
FILE *temp;
temp=fopen("temp","w");
fwrite(three_dim,outer_dim*ROWS*COLUMNS,1,temp);
fclose(temp);
```

EDIT:

Here is how it is allocated:

```
three_dim=new char**[outer_dim];
         for(int i=0;i<outer_dim;++i)
            {
                three_dim[i]=new char*[ROWS];
                for(int k=0;k<ROWS;++k)
                    three_dim[i][k]=new char[COLUMNS];
            }
```

Comment: How did you allocate it? It probably fails because it is not allocated compactly, but as an "array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays".

Comment: *How* does it fail?  Does it crash?  Does it write nothing?  Does it write garbage?  Secondly, is this C or C++?  You're using C-style I/O, but C++-style memory allocation.  Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write it into file by a single `fwrite()`, because your array is not allocated as a compact area of `outer_dim * ROWS * COLUMNS` bytes.

As you allocated it in a for-cycle, you must also output it in a for-cycle.

```
for (i = 0; i < outer_dim; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < ROWS; j++)
        fwrite(three_dim[i][j], COLUMNS, 1, temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, the most likely issue is that the memory hasn't been allocated contiguously.

If your ROWS and COLUMNS are compile-time constants, you could do something like the following:

```
char (*three_dim)[ROWS][COLUMNS]; // declare three_dim as a pointer to a 
                                  // ROWSxCOLUMNS array of char
...
three_dim = malloc(sizeof *three_dim * outer_dim);
```

You can then access `three_dim` as a 3-D array:

```
three_dim[i][j][k] = something();
```

This will allocate the data contiguously, and you should be able to write it in a single `fwrite` call as

```
fwrite(three_dim, sizeof *three_dim * outer_dim, 1, temp);
```

Otherwise, imp's solution is the way to go.

Comment: If I could accept two answers. I would have accepted yours too.